# PHP: Get data from database to feed JQuery chart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

data.php is returning:

```
{name: 'orcamento', data: [14000.00,8500.00,0.00]},{name: 'real', data: [2038.00,120.00,15000.00]},{name: 'desvio', data: [-11962.00,-8380.00,15000.00]}
```

I want to use this data to feed a chart. If I type the following code, it works well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options={
        chart: {
            renderTo:'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total Anual'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Vendas', 'Serviços', 'Outras']
        },
        series: [{name: 'orcamento', data: [14000.00,8500.00,0.00]},{name: 'real', data: [2038.00,120.00,15000.00]},{name: 'desvio', data: [-11962.00,-8380.00,15000.00]}]
    };
});
```

But the following code doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options={
        chart: {
            renderTo:'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total Anual'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Vendas', 'Serviços', 'Outras']
        },
        series: [$.get('data.php')]
    };
});
```

Why?

EDIT: I also tried this without luck:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dados=[];
    $.ajax({
        url:'data.php',
        success: function(response){
            dados=response
        }
    });

    var options={
        chart: {
            renderTo:'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total Anual'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Vendas', 'Serviços', 'Outras']
        },
        series: [dados] 
    };
});
```

EDIT2: Also tried the following but I get an empty chart:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dados=[];

    $.ajax({
        url:'data.php',
        success: function(response){
            dados=response
        },
        async:false
    });

    var options={
        chart: {
            renderTo:'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total Anual'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Vendas', 'Serviços', 'Outras']
        },
        series: [dados] 
    };

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

In JSONLint, I get the error:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    name: 'orcamento', 
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Comment: First off, you need to return valid JSON.  It looks like you need an array wrapper `[]` around your entire JSON structure. Second, you can load async result into a variable like you are attempting to do, you need to set options.series from within a success callback to `$.get()`

Comment: Thanks, I checked JSONLint, and I got: Parse error on line 1:
{    name: 'orcamento', 
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your edit question, the dados var probably isn't set when you define options. Because ajax response is made asynchronous. Try editing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dados=[];
    var options = {};
    $.ajax({
        url:'data.php',
        success: function(response){
            dados=$.parseJSON(response); // EDITED
            options={
                chart: {
                    renderTo:'container',
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Anual'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Vendas', 'Serviços', 'Outras']
                },
                series: [dados] 
            };
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        }
    });
});
```

In PHP JSON result, put [] like this:

> [{name: 'orcamento', data: [14000.00,8500.00,0.00]},{name: 'real',
>   data: [2038.00,120.00,15000.00]},{name: 'desvio', data:
>   [-11962.00,-8380.00,15000.00]}]

Comment: Thanks, I tried your proposal, I got Uncaught Highcharts error #13: It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where is the call for chart function? Check if this is call after ajax success too.

Comment: See my answer edited. You can use async:false too like suggested, by I personaly prefer put inside jQuery ajax call.

Comment: The data pulled from the server is: [{name: 'orcamento', data: [14000.00,8500.00,0.00]},
   {name: 'real', data: [2038.00,120.00,15000.00]},
   {name: 'desvio', data: [-11962.00,-8380.00,15000.00]}] . I get an error in JSONLint "Parse error on line 2:
[    {        name: 'orcamento', 
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'" and no chart.

Comment: Also tried it, please see my new question, since it seems the problem is the JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700048/how-to-convert-mysql-table-into-json-using-php

Comment: I see than you cannot resolve your question? Post a question on pt.stackoverflow.com, Is more easy for me to help in portuguese language.

Answer (score 0):

$.get('data.php') will ignore the return results.
See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

You have to use a callback.

Cheers,
J

Comment: Agreed, also make sure the output headers are set to `application/json` in data.php

Comment: Thanks, I changed my script, but still I get nothing: var dados=[];
 $.ajax({
  url:'data.php',
  success: function(response){
   dados=response
  }
 });
 
 var options={
  chart: {
   renderTo:'container',
   type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
   text: 'Total Anual'
  },
  xAxis: {
   categories: ['Vendas', 'Serviços', 'Outras']
  },
  series: [dados] 
 };
 
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);