# How to convert MySQL table into JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

How do I convert this:

[image: MySQL table]

Into a valid JSON file using PHP?

I tried:

```
$sql="SELECT ... more code here";

$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$real= implode(",",array_map(function($a) { return $a["real"]; }, $rows));
$orcamento = implode(",",array_map(function($a) { return $a["orcamento"]; }, $rows));
$desvio = implode(",",array_map(function($a) { return $a["desvio"]; }, $rows));


echo "{'name': 'orcamento', 'data': [$orcamento]},
        {'name': 'real', 'data': [$real]},
        {'name': 'desvio', 'data': [$desvio]}";
```

That returns:

```
{'name': 'orcamento', 'data': [14000.00,8500.00,0.00]},
    {'name': 'real', 'data': [2038.00,120.00,15000.00]},
    {'name': 'desvio', 'data': [-11962.00,-8380.00,15000.00]}
```

Which according to JSONLint is invalid (and I think the reason why the rest of my code isn't working. I get:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    'name': 'orcamento',
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

So my question is: How do I fix my PHP code in order to get a valid JSON?

EDIT:
I also tried:

```
$sql="SELECT ....";

$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$registos= json_encode($rows);

echo $registos;
```

That returns a valid JSON, but with the wrong format:

```
[
    {
        "real": "2038.00",
        "orcamento": "14000.00",
        "desvio": "-11962.00"
    },
    {
        "real": "120.00",
        "orcamento": "8500.00",
        "desvio": "-8380.00"
    },
    {
        "real": "15000.00",
        "orcamento": "0.00",
        "desvio": "15000.00"
    }
]
```

Comment: `echo json_encode($rows);` ?

Comment: Don't ever write your own JSON.  Always use `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Peter: yes, that was my first attempt, it returns a valid JSON but with the wrong structure. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be on the safe side, use `json_encode` like this:

```
$real = array_map(function($a) { return $a["real"]; }, $rows);
$orcamento = array_map(function($a) { return $a["orcamento"]; }, $rows);
$desvio = array_map(function($a) { return $a["desvio"]; }, $rows);

echo json_encode(array(
    array('name' => 'orcamento', 'data' => $orcamento),
    array('name' => 'real', 'data' => $real),
    array('name' => 'desvio', 'data' => $desvio)
));
```

(but in essence in your original output the `[` and `]` to surround the objects are missing and you need to use double quotes `"` for quoting the keys and strings)

Comment: Thanks, that is returning the numbers in 'data' surrounded by quotes, like: [
    {
        "name": "orcamento",
        "data": [
            "14000.00",
            "8500.00",
            "0.00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "real",
        "data": [
            "2038.00",
            "120.00",
            "15000.00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "desvio",
        "data": [
            "-11962.00",
            "-8380.00",
            "15000.00"
        ]
    }
]

Comment: Add a `floatval()` like this: `$real = array_map(function($a) { return floatval($a["real"]); }, $rows);`

Comment: But mind you that this will strip the `.00`. It doesn't make much sense to have formatted numbers in JSON. But after all, if you modify your original code to use `"` instead of `'` it should work, too, as I wrote in my answer already

Comment: That's important, since these are financial figures, we need the decimals. Your solution is returning "name" and "data" and it should be name and data without the quotes.

Comment: You misunderstand the concept of numeric values in programming languages. If you want to have a value of any kind in a specific format, you need to use a string, therefore it needs to be in quotes, there is no way around that.

Comment: Ok, I went back to the original proposal, it returns a valid JSON and that was my question. It doesn't solve my problem - to feed a chart - and I have no idea why, although if I hardcode the figures, it works. Anyway, I'll accept your answer and try to ask another question. Thanks for your help!